# Quitar Sugerencias de Texto VS Code

Tags: vscode

Quisiera saber cómo quitar estas sugerencias de VS Code, parece que no son creadas por el IntelliSense de PHP, sino por VS Code

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando Realmente es el IntelliSense me aparece así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias De antemano

Answer (score 0):

Ve a Extentions y busca:

```
 @builtin php
```

Aparecerá como opción `PHP Language Features`, da clic en el icono del engrane y selecciona `Disable`, esto deshabilitará las sugerencias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]